# What does \+ mean in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

I've seen some answers here that use it and I don't know what it means or how to use it. I's also hard to look for it via a search engine :)

Comment: The Prolog Dictionary might prove useful in the future: http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~billw/prologdict.html

Comment: W.r.t. the shape of the operator, in logic "provable" is usually written as a turnstile: |- . So in "not provable" \+ the \ stands for the long vertical bar and the vertical bar in the + stands for a slash doing the negation.

Comment: @starblue That's pretty far off lol. Why couldn't they use `|+`? Or just `~` or `!` like the rest of the world.

Comment: Just for clarification: `!` is an already defined operator that says "discard all choicepoints for this call" called a cut operator. `Not provable` means the question can't be answered at this time, not that the answer is false. An example would be "Is the inputstream going to send more data?" which can only be determined when there's an **external** timeout or a termination signal, not from inside the streamreader itself.

Comment: A plus sign going down a slide having fun?

Comment: http://www.cse.unsw.edu.au/~billw/dictionaries/prolog/negation.html

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It's the '[not provable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prolog#Negation)' operator.  It succeeds if its argument is not provable (and fails if its argument is provable).

Comment: so \+(cat(X)) is the same as not(cat(X)) ?

Comment: Yes, it's just a detail of your implementation.  This link mentions some examples: http://www.csupomona.edu/~jrfisher/www/prolog_tutorial/2_5.html

Comment: @JuanjoConti: SWI has both `not/1` and `\+`, but recmmends - based on the documentation - to use `\+`. The `not/1` is - given I understood it correctly - for backwards compatibility.

Comment: @CarlNorum - Your link is broken

Comment: @G_V - just checked, looks fine. It's just the wikipedia page for prolog, so easy enough to look up if you need to.

Comment: @CarlNorum http://www.csupomona.edu/~jrfisher/www/prolog_tutorial/2_5.html doesn't work for me

Comment: Oh different link - gotcha. I thought you meant the one in the answer. Anyway, doesn't really matter - just syntax differences between implementations.

Answer (score 11):

It's do with negation. `\+ Goal` will succeed if `Goal` cannot be proven.

Comment: Looks like your backslash got eaten.  I stuck it back in there.

Comment: so \+(cat(X)) is the same as not(cat(X)) ?

Comment: "not" is usually some form of (safe) negation, whereas `\+` just means: fail, if the goal is provable *at this point in time* quantifying all variables existentially.

Comment: Aaah, so `not` expects a result of `true` or `false`, but `\+` only has to be syntactically correct and gives back `true` if there simply is no way to satisfy the goal at all? Let's say, 'Is my stream at its end yet?' will return true as long as the end hasn't been reached.

Answer (score 0):

The way I memorize it is through the following logical rule:

- `\+` = 'if `unsure` or `false`, assume `false`'

This is different from standard boolean logic in that if your goal is uncertain instead of outright true or false, it assumes false when it can't prove true. The most obvious example of this is being unable to see whether a stream is still open or not. If you can't prove it is open, it's the same as being closed to the program.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negation_as_failure

Comment: Did you mean `assume true' ?