# Find the max element and its index in a list - Prolog

Tags: list, prolog

I am fresh in Prolog. And I am trying to write a predicate that finds the Max value and its index of a list of integers. i.e `max_list([2,3,4], MAX, INDEX)` will yield `MAX=4`, `INDEX=2`

Thank you for reply~ My apologize! This is the first time I ask questions in stackoverflow. I could write a predicate to find the maximum or a minimum of a list, but I don't know how to get the exact position the value in the list. I am just trying to comprehend the answers.

Comment: You need to show an attempt and explain what problems you have encountered

Comment: Which solution(s) do you expect for `?- max_list([1,2,1],Max,Index).` ?

Answer (score 4):

Using [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd) ...

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).
```

..., [meta-predicate](/questions/tagged/meta-predicate)  [`maplist/2`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6683502/4609915), and `nth0/3` we define:

```
zs_maximum_at(Zs,Max,Pos) :-
   maplist(#>=(Max),Zs),
   nth0(Pos,Zs,Max).
```

Here's the query the OP gave:

```
?- zs_maximum_at([2,3,4],M,I).
I = 2, M = 4.
```

OK! ... how about the *most general* query?

```
?- zs_maximum_at(Zs,M,I).
  Zs = [M], I = 0, M in inf..sup
; Zs = [ M,_B], I = 0, M #>= _B
; Zs = [_A, M], I = 1, M #>= _A
; Zs = [ M,_B,_C], I = 0, M #>= _B, M #>= _C
; Zs = [_A, M,_C], I = 1, M #>= _A, M #>= _C
; Zs = [_A,_B, M], I = 2, M #>= _A, M #>= _B
; Zs = [ M,_B,_C,_D], I = 0, M #>= _B, M #>= _C, M #>= _D
; Zs = [_A, M,_C,_D], I = 1, M #>= _A, M #>= _C, M #>= _D
...
```

---

**Edit:** What about arithmetic *expressions*?

1. We can *allow* the use of arithmetic expressions by adding an additional goal `(#=)/2`:

   ```
   zs_maximum_at(Zs,Expr,Pos) :-
      maplist(#>=(Max),Zs),
      nth0(Pos,Zs,Expr),
      Expr #= Max.
   ```

   Now we can run queries like the following one—but lose monotonicity (cf. [this clpfd manual](http://www.swi-prolog.org/man/clpfd.html))!

   ```
   ?- zs_maximum_at([0+1,1+1,2-0,3-1,1+0],M,I).
     I = 1, M = 1+1
   ; I = 2, M = 2-0
   ; I = 3, M = 3-1
   ; false.
   ```
2. To *disable* arithmetic expressions we can use [`length/2`](https://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/ulrich/iso-prolog/prologue) in combination with [`ins/2`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/man/clpfd.html):

   ```
   zs_maximum_at(Zs,Max,Pos) :-
      length(Zs,_),
      Zs ins inf..sup,
      maplist(#>=(Max),Zs),
      nth0(Pos,Zs,Max).
   ```

   Running above query again, we now get:

   ```
   ?- zs_maximum_at([0+1,1+1,2-0,3-1,1+0],M,I).
   ERROR: Type error: `integer' expected, found `0+1' (a compound)
   ```

Note that the issue (of allowing arithmetic expressions or not) is not limited to [clpfd](/questions/tagged/clpfd).
It is also present when using plain-old Prolog arithmetic predicates like `is/2` and friends.

Comment: Very elegant and general solution!

Comment: Thank you! Your answer and explanation is quite clear!

Answer (score 2):

I'm no Prolog expert myself so this is probably not the most beautiful solution, but this predicate should do what you want:

```
max_list([X|Xs],Max,Index):-
    max_list(Xs,X,0,0,Max,Index).

max_list([],OldMax,OldIndex,_, OldMax, OldIndex).
max_list([X|Xs],OldMax,_,CurrentIndex, Max, Index):-
    X > OldMax,
    NewCurrentIndex is CurrentIndex + 1,
    NewIndex is NewCurrentIndex,
    max_list(Xs, X, NewIndex, NewCurrentIndex, Max, Index).
max_list([X|Xs],OldMax,OldIndex,CurrentIndex, Max, Index):-
    X =< OldMax,
    NewCurrentIndex is CurrentIndex + 1,
    max_list(Xs, OldMax, OldIndex, NewCurrentIndex, Max, Index).
```

Comment: s(X): Ok,  better now!

Comment: Thank you~ This solution is easy to understand!

Answer (score 2):

a variation on joel76 answer:

```
max_list(L, M, I) :- nth0(I, L, M), \+ (member(E, L), E > M).
```

Comment: If anyone else stumbles across this: `\+` is the'[not provable operator', see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1712034/what-does-mean-in-prolog

Answer (score 1):

Another approach, not very efficient but more "prologish" is to say :
What is the max of a list ? it's a member of the list, and no other member of this list is greater than the max !
So :

```
max_list(Lst, Max, Ind) :-
   member(Max, Lst),
   \+((member(N, Lst), N > Max)),
   % Now, with SWI-Prolog, (may be with other Prolog)
   % nth0/3 gives you the index of an element in a list
   nth0(Ind, Lst, Max).
```

Comment: s(X): Ok! Instead of `\+((member(N,Lst), N > Max))` one could use `maplist(>=(Max),Lst)`. (This is not 100% equivalent, but allows using [tag:clpfd] instead of plain-old Prolog integer arithmetic...)